# Add Extension To Color

Tags: c#, colors

I want to add extension to the `Color` struct

My Code :

```
public static Color myExt(this Color clr)
{
    if (clr == Color.Black)
        clr = Color.White;
    else
        clr = Color.Black;
    return clr;
}
```

I can only use it by :

```
this.BackColor = this.BackColor.myExt();
```

How i can use it by Command :

```
this.BackColor = Color.myExt();
```

Thanks,

Comment: You can call it as `YourExtensionMethodClassName.myExt(yourColor);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"By command"? Well, if you mean you can simply add a static method to `Color` than the answer is "not at all" as all your (extension-)methods belong to a user-defined class instead of an existing one. Thus what you actually do when creating an extension-method is create a static method in any custom assembly that expects an `instance` (that´s why there is a `this` in the signature) of the extended class. So the call to `this.BackColor = this.BackColor.myExt();` is equivalent to `this.BackColor = MyColourExtensions.myExt(this.BackColor);`

However the class `Color` itself is not modified in any way by extension-methods. So what you want to achieve can simpy not be done. Even if it were possible to add a static method to an existing class your code won´t work, as you still need an instance of `Color` as dictated by your method-signature.

What you CAN do is omit the this-keyword from your signature and call the method from your static class as `MyColourExtensions.myExt()` requiring no argument at all.

Comment: So, That means , i cant use it like : `this.BackColor = Color.myExt()` .. :( ?

Comment: Yeap. However why would you want this? Your method obviously needs an instance of `Color` to work on which you do not want to provide for any reason.

Comment: I just asked this to see why i can't use it , anyway ... thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't use it like that because "Extension methods are a special kind of static method, but they are called as if they were **instance** methods on the extended type." [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

You can use it like that instead:

```
this.BackColor = new Color().myExt();
```